# outlook calendar api redirection uri with vhost , not working

Tags: redirect, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

i am trying to integrate outlook calendar using following links,
https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/php , i have added my app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. the example app working fine, with localhost redirect uri

```
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/php-tutorial/authorize.php';
```

but when i have used my vhost local uri (http://www.gcal2excel.dev/authorize.php), and updated redirect uri in [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com][1] , redirect stops working and showing following error:

```
Array
(
    [error] => invalid_request
    [error_description] => The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The scope 'openid https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read' requires that the request must be sent over a secure connection using SSL.
)
```

seeking solution for this, should i implement SSL certificate in my local vhost? so connection will be using SSL? how to do that for local vhost?

Comment: Unfortunately only localhost works with http.
What about a test or staging environment on cloud? Do we need an ssl certificate for these envs as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You MUST use SSL for redirect URIs. The **only** exception is localhost.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, can you suggest how to implement  SSL for redirect URIs? :)

Comment: You'll have to refer to the docs for whatever web server you're using.